# third speed of the fan

Tags: phrase-request

I have a fan with three different levels of speed, level 3 being the fastest speed. How should I ask someone in English to turn on the fan so that it would be the third speed?

I was thinking of "Turn on the third speed of the fan, please.", but I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the speed that is turned on, but the fan. “Turn on the fan, to the third speed” or ”turn on the fan to the third speed” would be correct.

You could also say “**set** the fan to the third speed. This works whether the fan is on already or not.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the main options are:

- "put the fan on the highest speed"
- "set the fan speed to the highest one"
- "hit the button for the highest speed"

... Noting that you can substitute "the third speed" or "speed three" depending on your familiarity with the fan.

Also, if it has three speeds, you're likely to refer to them as low, medium, and high. "Can you put the fan on high, please?"

Answer (score 1):

> Set the fan to the third speed